# Unable to use body-parser with Router in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am working with Nodejs and using expressjs,Right now i am trying to use "body-parser" with "router" but right now i am getting following error [object object],How can i solve this ? Here is my "api.router.js" file

```
const express = require('express');
const apiController = require('../controllers/api.controller');
const router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// Endpoint for creating a new record
router.post('/new', apiController.addUser);
module.exports = router;
```

And here is my "api.controller.js"

```
const User = require('../models/user.model');
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
const { firstName, lastName, age } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  ...
}
```

Comment: (1) body parser is exposed through the express object so you don’t need to make it a direct dependency and require it (2) You have required body parser but *not done anything* with the `bodyParser` variable (3) `[object Object]` isn’t an error and you haven’t told us which piece of code is reporting it. (4) You haven’t shown us what the request (in particular the body and content type) look like. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: to properly log the object, do this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));`

Answer (score 1):

remove the following line from your code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

And instead, add the following code to your api.router.js file, before defining the routes:

```
router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of usage explained by the author

[Express/Connect top-level generic](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic)
And
[Express route-specific](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#express-route-specific)

You can use any one of them or conditionally use based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.use(bodyParser.json());`  or  `app.use(express.json());`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const helloworld_route = require("./routes/helloworld");

const port = process.env.PORT || 2000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/", helloworld_route);

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```